# Are there encryption methods that appear like "standard" communication rather than cipher output?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

When encrypting information, the output is typically garbled ciphertext. Is there an encryption standard that produces ciphertext that looks like a standard, comprehensible message in the language in which it's created.

An example of what I mean is something like taking the first letter of every word in a message to assemble another message.

(I ask this is purely curiosity -- I have no need for this standard if it exists.)

Comment: What you are asking about sounds like steganography or a variant of it. Really, such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: No, I don't thik so. The closest thing is the Caesar and Vigenere ciphers which produce ascii characters with the same format as the original message, but still the content would be gibberish, and also it's trivial to break those ciphers. You could create this type of 'ciphertext' by hand, but it wouldn't be any secure.

Comment: You could have a look at [Format-Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) which does some of what you are asking.

Comment: @rossum FPE is not comprehensible.

Comment: @kelalaka What part of it do you not understand?

Comment: @rossum He wants the encrypted result like a paragraph, book, that is what understand.

Comment: @kelalaka That is why I said "some of" in my first comment.

Comment: @rossum Base64 encoding is also some of after AES-CBC.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any such standards. You could create one yourself, though.

For example, you could map the 256 bytes to one and two letter sequences, that are commonly used to begin words. Then you encrypt your message using a secure modern cipher, like AES. Then you map each ciphertext byte to the corresponding letter sequence, and create a word from each. It would be difficult (but perhaps not impossible!) to automate this to produce somewhat legible English.

The result would be secure. The only downside is that the resulting encoded ciphertext would explode in size.